# Saving the value of toggle buttons when activity gets destroyed and put them back when activity starts again

Tags: java, android, save, toggle, onsaveinstancestate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GzdS.jpg)Good day, I want to save the value of the toggle buttons when the app exits and put them back when the user starts the app again. I've tried using onSaveInstanceState but it just doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

edit: I also tried using preferences.
edit: I also tried using preferences.
edit: I also tried using preferences.
edit: I also tried using preferences.
edit: I also tried using preferences.
edit: I also tried using preferences.

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("white", white.isChecked());
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("yellow", yellow.isChecked());
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("orange", orange.isChecked());
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("red", red.isChecked());
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("blue", blue.isChecked());
        savedInstanceState.putInt("whiteI", whiteI.getVisibility());
        savedInstanceState.putInt("yellowI", yellowI.getVisibility());
        savedInstanceState.putInt("orangeI", orangeI.getVisibility());
        savedInstanceState.putInt("redI", redI.getVisibility());
        savedInstanceState.putInt("blueI", blueI.getVisibility());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        white.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("white"));
        yellow.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("yellow"));
        orange.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("orange"));
        red.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("red"));
        blue.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("blue"));

        whiteI.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("whiteI"));
        yellowI.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("yellowI"));
        orangeI.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("orangeI"));
        redI.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("redI"));
        blueI.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("blueI"));


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editPreferences = preferences.edit();
        editPreferences.putBoolean("white", white.isChecked());
        editPreferences.putBoolean("yellow", yellow.isChecked());
        editPreferences.putBoolean("orange", orange.isChecked());
        editPreferences.putBoolean("red", red.isChecked());
        editPreferences.putBoolean("blue", blue.isChecked());
        editPreferences.putInt("whiteI", whiteI.getVisibility());
        editPreferences.putInt("yellowI", yellowI.getVisibility());
        editPreferences.putInt("orangeI", orangeI.getVisibility());
        editPreferences.putInt("redI", redI.getVisibility());
        editPreferences.putInt("blueI", blueI.getVisibility());
        editPreferences.commit();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) Toast.makeText(this, "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        background = findViewById(R.id.imageViewBg);
        yellow = findViewById(R.id.tgBtnAlarm);
        orange = findViewById(R.id.tgBtnAlert);
        red = findViewById(R.id.tgBtnCritical);
        blue = findViewById(R.id.tgBtnRecession);
        white = findViewById(R.id.tgBtnNormal);

        yellowI = findViewById(R.id.imageViewYellow);
        redI = findViewById(R.id.imageViewRed);
        blueI = findViewById(R.id.imageViewBlue);
        orangeI = findViewById(R.id.imageViewOrange);
        whiteI = findViewById(R.id.imageViewWhite);

        btnExit = findViewById(R.id.btnExit);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_PRIVATE);
        white.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("white"));
        yellow.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("yellow"));
        orange.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("orange"));
        red.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("red"));
        blue.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("blue"));
        whiteI.setVisibility(preferences.getInt("whiteI"));
        yellowI.setVisibility(preferences.getInt("yellowI"));
        orangeI.setVisibility(preferences.getInt("orangeI"));
        redI.setVisibility(preferences.getInt("redI"));
        blueI.setVisibility(preferences.getInt("blueI"));

        glide();
        allow();
        volume();

        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               finish();
            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences savePreferences = getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editPreferences = savePreferences.edit();
editPreferences.putBoolean("white", white.isChecked());
editPreferences.putBoolean("yellow", yellow.isChecked());
editPreferences.putBoolean("orange", orange.isChecked());
editPreferences.putBoolean("red", red.isChecked());
editPreferences.putBoolean("blue", blue.isChecked());
editPreferences.putInt("whiteI", whiteI.getVisibility());
editPreferences.putInt("yellowI", yellowI.getVisibility());
editPreferences.putInt("orangeI", orangeI.getVisibility());
editPreferences.putInt("redI", redI.getVisibility());
editPreferences.putInt("blueI", blueI.getVisibility());
editPreferences.commit();
```

To retrive data

```
    white.setChecked(savePreferences.getBoolean("white"));
    yellow.setChecked(savePreferences.getBoolean("yellow"));
    orange.setChecked(savePreferences.getBoolean("orange"));         
    red.setChecked(savePreferences.getBoolean("red"));
    blue.setChecked(savePreferences.getBoolean("blue"));    
    whiteI.setVisibility(savePreferences.getInt("whiteI"));
    yellowI.setVisibility(savePreferences.getInt("yellowI"));
    orangeI.setVisibility(savePreferences.getInt("orangeI"));
    redI.setVisibility(savePreferences.getInt("redI"));
    blueI.setVisibility(savePreferences.getInt("blueI"));
```

Comment: already tried that but it's not working too. I put the shared preferences in the onPause method and the retrieve in the onCreate. Also, at the code for retrieve, it gives this error (getInt(String, int) in sharedpreferences cannot be applied to (String) )

Comment: Implement both the methods i.e updating and retrieving in the onCreate. At first check if the SharedPreferences is set to null, if it is set to null then invoke update function or else invoke retrieve function.  Coming to the error can you post the logs to see where exactly the error is showing up.